# SED - Insert file at top of another

Tags: sed

I have been trying to insert a file as the first line of another with following SED command, without much success. Each time the file is inserted after line 1. Is there a switch that will inserted before line 1?

```
sed -i '1r file1.txt' file2.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sed` command `r` will place the contents of the specified file in the output before reading the next line of input. Unfortunately you can't specify `0` as the address for this command, so there's no way to insert the contents of a file before the first line of input (without poking around with the hold space).

You could, however, just use plain old `cat`. It is, after all, *the* command for concatenating files:

```
$ cat file1.txt file2.txt >out && mv out file2.txt
```

To be sure you're writing to a temporary file that does not already exist, one may use the `mktemp` utility:

```
$ tmp="$(mktemp)" && cat file1.txt file2.txt >"$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file2.txt
```

This is slightly awkward on the command line, but a good precaution in any script that needs to write to a temporary file.

Comment: I suggest with the use of *mktemp*:  `tmp=$(mktemp) && cat file1.txt file2.txt > $tmp && mv $tmp file2.txt` ?

Comment: @Danduk82 That's a reasonable suggestion.

Comment: Thought of that - the text files are over 1.5 GB, takes  a while. but if that is the only option!  it will have to do!  thank you.

Comment: all good  - did not take a long as i expected. ! 8-)

Comment: @user68650 There is never only one option ;-)

Comment: @user68650: At a bare minimum, the functionality that you want requires reading `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` in their entirety, and writing a new version of `file2.txt` (containing the original content of the two files, concatenated).  `mktemp` and `mv` are very low-cost operations (except when `mv` really does a copy); why would you expect there to be an answer that’s more efficient than this?

Answer (score 7):

## With the `N` command

Provided that `file2.txt` has more than one line (else see the other section):

```
sed -i -e '1 { r file1.txt' -e 'N; }' file2.txt
```

The trick is to defer the printing of the first line with the `N` command.

From the manual:

> N
>
> Append the next line of input into the pattern space.

## With the `e` command

Provided that `file2.txt` is not empty (else just do a copy):

```
sed -i -e '1 e cat file1.txt' file2.txt
```

GNU `sed` provides a `e` command that executes the command in parameter. The result is output is immediately.

From the manual:

> e [COMMAND]
>
> This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into
>   pattern space.  Without parameters, the `e' command executes the
>   command that is found in pattern space and replaces the pattern
>   space with the output; a trailing newline is suppressed.
>
> If a parameter is specified, instead, the `e' command interprets
>   it as a command and sends its output to the output stream.
>
> Note that, unlike the 'r' command, the output of the command will
>   be printed immediately; the 'r' command instead delays the output
>   to the end of the current cycle.

Comment: Hi,  What do the curly braces do in the first example ?

Comment: @Stelios They associate a group of commands to a single address (here line 1)

Answer (score 5):

If you're determined to avoid `cat`ing to an explicit temporary file (or via a buffer such as `sponge`), then it looks like `ed` at least will accept a 0-address for its `r` command:

```
ed -s file2.txt << EOF
0r file1.txt
wq
EOF
```

or equivalently

```
printf '0r file1.txt\nwq\n' | ed -s file2.txt
```

Comment: Yes, `ed` is always a good choice when we don't need the `s` (streaming) of `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert the same file on top of multiple files within the same directory, the following based on [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337438/147432) might be used:

```
for i in file*; do tmp="$(mktemp)" && cat file1 $i >"$tmp" && mv "$tmp" $i; done
```

Comment: That should work. Nice lateral thinking, and welcome to unix.se